# There is some way to overwrite the MaterialDesignPaper brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml, dynamicresource

I have a **WPF** application with **MaterialDesign** for **XAML**: https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit

I was able to verify that the MaterialDesignPaper brush changes dynamically when you change the mode (light,dark), But I want to change the color for the light theme.

There is some way to override or change the color of the brush only for the light theme, and keep its color change property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Brush names as mentioned [Here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Brush-Names)

Example:

- PrimaryHueLightBrush
- PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush
- PrimaryHueMidBrush

And so on..

Create your custom as [shown here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Custom-Palette-Hues)

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightBrush" Color="#744CE0"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryHueMidBrush" Color="#6134D9"/>
....
```

Arbitrary colors in backend C# code

```
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System.Windows.Media;
...
Color primaryColor = Colors.Purple;
Color secondaryColor = Colors.Lime;

IBaseTheme baseTheme = Theme.Light;
//If you want a dark theme you can use IBaseTheme baseTheme = Theme.Dark;

ITheme theme = Theme.Create(baseTheme, primaryColor, secondaryColor);
```

You can get more info on themes, palettes and brushes on their [Wiki](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki) page